# Android - HttpURLConnection count bytes

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I send some data to server I use httpURLConnection and DataOutputStream.

```
DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
outputStream.write(data);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Is there a way to check if i have sent all bytes?
I mean there is something like getContentLength() but it return -1 so i guess it contains only a length which i set in header. i have to be sure if i sent e.g. 500/500 bytes(not only 480/500 bytes). so is there a way to check it? or all i can do is valid data at server side and send response?

Comment: off-topic comment: Any reason for using `DataOutputStream` ? from docs *`DataOutputStream` - A data output stream **lets an application write primitive Java data types** to an output stream in a portable way.* ... HTTP is programming language independent, so there is no need(and no sens) for writing primitive Java data types

Comment: I need to send byte array. There is high probability i will send data only with JSON, but at this moment i send some data with using JSON and some with DataOutputStream. So in fact i would like to resolve my problem by using httpURLConnection  if it is possible.